# Magento2 : Cache file path displayed in home page

Tags: magento2, error, cache, home-page

> /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/container.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/head.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-google-analytics/view/frontend/templates/ga.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/MagicToolbox/MagicZoom/view/frontend/templates/html/head.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe_popup.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Plumrocket/SocialLoginFree/view/frontend/templates/customer/form/register/sharepopup.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/js/polyfill.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-translation/view/base/templates/translate.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/js/cookie.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-cookie/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/logger.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Plumrocket/SocialLoginFree/view/frontend/templates/general.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/custom_notice.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/sidebar_sticky.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/html/header.phtml
>   /home/healthba/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/fro

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission issue. please check the permissions once.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html